# Are left and right Kan extensions ever isomorphic?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kan-extension

So I wonder if it is possible that a left Kan extension of a fully faithful functor $F$ along some other fully faithful functor $G$ (over a small category) agrees with (is isomorphic to) the right Kan extension of $F$ along $G$ - of course when these are defined.

(In fact, the codomain categories of the functors I have in mind are bicomplete, so I do not worry about existence).

Comment: How about when the first source category is empty and you Kan extend along the inclusion to a point? Then any target category with a zero object will do.

Comment: @John Menor: incidentally, while I recognize that you only assume the _source_ category to be small, and the _target_ category to be complete, it appears not irrelevant to mention here that if a small category is complete, then it is a quasiorder.

Comment: Let $e$ be the trivial category with one object and just the identity morphism, $\mathcal A$ the category of abelian groups, and $e_G$ the category associated to a finite group $G$. Thus $e_G$ has one object, and the morphisms are elements of $G$. Let $f:e\to \mathcal A$ be the functor that sends the object to an abelian group $A$. Let $G:e\to e_G$ be the obvious inclusion. Then the left and right extensions of $F$ along $G$ are isomorphic. More precisely, they send the unique object of $e_G$ to $A[G]$ and $A^G$ respectively, which are isomorphic $G$-modules.

Comment: I think the OP was restricting his question to extensions along fully faithful inclusions, which excludes the example e-->e_G

Comment: Ooops, you are right.

Comment: Just to add a bit more structure, and put this into context, especially for "onlookers": there is the following hierarchy of "connections" between right and left Kan extensions: (0) by the very definition of Kan extensions, for each particular functor $F$, _if_ both $\mathrm{Ran}_GF$ and $\mathrm{Lan}_GF$ exist, they are (rather tenuously) "connected" in the sense that there is a natural transformation $(\mathrm{Ran}_GF)\circ G\Rightarrow (\mathrm{Lan}_GF)\circ G$. If (1) moreover for all functors _F_ both extensions exist, _then_ they are "more strongly" connected by [...]

Comment: [...] a chain of adjunctions $\mathrm{Lan}_G \dashv ( F\mapsto F\circ G) \dashv \mathrm{Ran}_G$ of functors between functor-categories. (No precise meaning of "more strongly connected" here.) The OP is asking if and when, assuming $G$ is fully faithful with domain-category small, there is a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Ran}_G F \cong \mathrm{Lan}_G F$. (And a minor criticism of the formulation of the OP: "over" should rather be _on_, and, more seriously, "when these are defined" had better be _when these both exist_. They are always _defined_.)

Comment: And to add more context: there are two recent textbooks, one in German, which both touch on this topic. Both authors seem to have decided to not clear up this issue. In one of them, an example involving the extension of the exponential-function-with-base-two from domain $\mathbb{Q}$ to domain $\mathbb{R}$ is shown to be an example of a Kan extension, and then it is mentioned at the end that "zuf"allig" the left and right Kan extensions result in the same functor. One should not read too much into one word. Literally, "zufallig" means "by chance", or "as if by fluke", but [...]

Comment: [...]as I said one should not read too much into one word, and perhaps the author is the one who should explain this. The other book treats a _variant_ of this extension problem, _different_ in that another bicomplete "target" category is used (namely $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$). Then it is mentioned that left and right Kan extension of the exponential-function-with-base-two-functor again are isomorphic functors, and then "invites the reader to explore" why they coincide. So we have one text suggesting that there is no general reasone, the other text [...]

Comment: [...] delegating the search for a reason to readers. This is not meant to be a criticisms of these two wonderful books---no one would ever finish a book if every direction would be explored; it is good to leave things to readers.

Comment: And to get back to the "hierarchy" of "connections" mentioned in another comment: since the OP assumes the target category to be bicomplete, and since the OP assumes $G$
to be full and faithful, it follows that the natural transformation mentioned in (0) is a natural isomorphism, that is, the OP's hypotheses always imply $({\rm Ran}_G F)\circ G\cong ({\rm Lan}_G F)\circ G$. From this isomorphism, more or less tautological answers can be obtained, possibly involving the concept of _being epic in a category of categories_. The OP did not ask for a characterization, only an example, though.

Comment: My intuitive understanding of Kan extension is that you have two functors, and the Kan extension of $G$ along $F$ is a functor that what precomposed with $F$ is the approximation of $G$. So, if loss of information about the initial category after manipulation by $F$ and $G$ the same, then the approximation will be an isomorphism.

Not sure if this interpretation is correct, some expert here, could clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Consider the left and right Kan extension along the terminal object $t: 1 \to \text{Set}$, applied to a functor $X: 1 \to \text{Sup}$ in the category of sup-lattices. The left Kan extension $\text{Set} \to \text{Sup}$ is the functor $\text{Set} \to \text{Sup}: A \to A \cdot X$ (the coproduct of $A$ copies of $X$), and the right Kan extension along $t: 1 \to \text{Set}$ takes $X: 1 \to \text{Sup}$ takes $A$ to $X^A$, the product of $A$ copies of $X$. (As a covariant functor in $A$, the latter functor takes a map $f: A \to B$ to the map $(\text{Ran}_t X)(f): X^A \to X^B$ which whose value at $g: A \to X$ is $B \to X: b \mapsto \bigvee_{f(a) = b} g(a)$.) The canonical transformation $A \cdot X \to X^A$ is a natural isomorphism of sup-lattices, so the right and left Kan extensions are isomorphic.

The point is that sup-lattices are infinitary commutative monoids; we are extrapolating from binary biproducts

$$X + X \cong X \times X$$

of commutative monoids to infinitary biproducts

$$A \cdot X = \sum_A X \cong \prod_A X \cong X^A$$

of sup-lattices.

Comment: Of course in general $X: 1 \to \text{Sup}$ is not fully faithful, but it sometimes is (e.g., $X$ the zero object), giving an especially trivial answer.